# Flash compile error

Tags: flash, compilation

i am creating a web site and when i compiled my flash code so it writing that

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference.  at
>   gallery_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

I dunno what is wrong, please help my with my problem.  thanks for your reply.

This is code from first frame in timeline...

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

evNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, evNexClick); function evNexClick(event:MouseEvent):void{ gotoAndPlay("remaxe"); }

evPrew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, evPreClick); function evPreClick(event:MouseEvent):void{ gotoAndPlay("remaxe"); }

reNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reNexClick); function reNexClick(event:MouseEvent):void{ gotoAndPlay("evalex"); }

rePrew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rePreClick); function rePreClick(event:MouseEvent):void{ gotoAndPlay("evalex"); }
```

thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0):

The code you have on your main timeline in frame 1 is trying to access something that doesn't exist. Post the code and we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

This is code from first frame in timeline...

> import flash.events.MouseEvent;
>
> evNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
>   evNexClick); function
>   evNexClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
>     gotoAndPlay("remaxe"); }
>
> evPrew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
>   evPreClick); function
>   evPreClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
>     gotoAndPlay("remaxe"); }
>
> reNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
>   reNexClick); function
>   reNexClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
>     gotoAndPlay("evalex"); }
>
> rePrew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
>   rePreClick); function
>   rePreClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
>     gotoAndPlay("evalex"); }

thanks for all answers